# Why does the addition of signed integers 0xA3 + 0xF9 NOT produce overflow, but the addition of signed integers 0x9F + 0xA3 does?

Tags: arithmetic, binary, number-systems

**I presented the Hexadecimal values for these integers in the title, just to preserve space, however I am actually trying to add them in Binary.**

The overflow conditions (from what I could understand) for signed binary Addition are as follows:

Suppose we have 2 integers *x* and *y*.

- If we are adding *x* and *y*, and they are both **positive**, but the result is **negative**, then there is overflow.
- Likewise, if we are adding *x* and *y*, and they are both **negative**, but the result is **positive**, then there is overflow.
- Lastly, if the Most Significant Bit Carry-In value is not equal to the MSB Carry-Out value, then there is overflow (I think this is the condition I am having the most trouble understanding, but that will be more clear after you've viewed the way I worked out both of these problems)

Now for the actual addition, I have attached my work:

[Calculations for both addition problems.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mz9a.jpg)

Firstly, am I even doing signed addition correctly? If so, then what is the point of 2's complement if I am just going to add these signed integers without even using it?

Secondly, in the first problem and the second, there is an extra 9th bit, however overflow only occurs in the second problem. What gives?

I thought I understood the concept of signed binary, however now that I am actually performing computations with 8-bit binary numbers, I have run into lots of confusion, especially where overflow is thrown into the mix. If you need any clarification or if I am breaking any rules, please let me know so I can edit my post accordingly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this a computing question rather than mathematics?

Comment: I had that same dilemma before posting. Originally I was going to ask on StackOverflow rather than here. Is that what I should do?

Comment: For both questions, both addends $x$ and $y$ are negative, the difference is that the first result $0x9C$ is negative, but the second result $0x42$ is positive.

Comment: @peterwhy I thought that both 0x9C and 0x42 both have a MSB of 1, so they would both be negative?

Comment: As an $8$-bit binary number, $0x42 = b0100\ 0010$, and the most-significant bit is $0$.

Comment: @peterwhy Okay that makes a bit more sense. Then my follow-up question would be, is the 9th bit taken into consideration at all when determining the overflow? Or is it solely dependent on the rules from above?